# Android Google Maps Util Icon not Centered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the Utils library to add some custom markers in the map. My code is pretty simple, just a copy from the library own example:

```
......
IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(getActivity());
addIcon(iconFactory, text, location, map); 

private void addIcon(IconGenerator iconFactory, String text, LatLng position, GoogleMap map) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
            icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(text))).
            position(position).
            anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

But my markers have their center shifted to the right. I send a big string to text and this became clear (the arrows point how the left and right are not the same length):

[image: center shifted]

I am using all that came with the library, so this is not my 9patch. How can I solve this?

(I am running it in an Android 4.0.3 tablet)

---

EDIT:

Ok, I tried this same code in an AVD running kitkat on a nexus 5, and the marker appears to be just fine:

[image]

Any clues if this is just a problem with 4.0.3?

Comment: Can you confirm that this works on physical devices running Android KitKat or higher?

Comment: Yes, this works on my Moto X running 5.0 and I remember it was just fine when it was kitkat

Comment: I'd say it's just an obsolete issue then.

Comment: There are plenty of devices still running 4.0, unfortunately in the Android world there ain't such a thing as obsolete issue, there is so much fragmentation, you have to worry about this stuff, if you want to expand your user base of course

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the Utils library as opposed to Google Maps Android API v2's infowindow?

Comment: Are you using Google Play Services by the way?

Comment: Yes I am using Google Play, and I use the utils library so I can add custom markers instead of the regular ones

Comment: You could try filing a bug for it on the Maps issue tracker.

Comment: I don't know if they care to fix bugs on old versions, probably all the fixes come in a new version of the system, I am not a specialist

Comment: I have the same issue on Android 6.0.1 (Nexus 5X, real device) using maps utils 0.4, except that the center caret is shifted to the left instead. Any ideas?

Comment: File a bug report with Google...